# Is it possible to send text data from an app to a firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to make an app which retrieve call records and sends it to a server (specific URL).I've managed to get call records in the form of strings but can't figure out how to send this data to firebase's databse.Is it possible to do so?

Comment: What do you mean by "without use of message service"? Firebase Cloud Messaging? I don't think that's part of your question since you seem to be asking about Firebase database

Comment: sorry i forgot to edit that. Been done !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After setting up firebase for your android app, the code to write to firebase is

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("callRecords");
Map<String, Object> callRecords = new HashMap<>();

//if you have a specific, unique label for your call record
callRecords.put(label1,callRecordString1)
callRecords.put(label2,callRecordString2)
//... put more call records

//OR... if you dont have a label, get a random key with Firebase
callRecords.put(ref.push().getKey() , callRecordString1)
callRecords.put(ref.push().getKey() , callRecordString2)
//... put more call records

ref.updateChildren(callRecords);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but what is the purpose of "Map<String, Object>"  ?

Comment: The purpose of the map is that the method updateChildren() takes in a map of key-value pairs. This way firebase knows which specific entries you are updating or adding. The map can have one or more entries based on how much data you want to change/add. If you're only adding new data, the two lines with push().getKey() are your solutions to adding callRecords. As for <String,Object>, this is simply the Map parameter type accepted by firebase.